# Getting GIMP Warnings From Cygwin in Windows

Tags: windows, cygwin, gimp

When I run `gimp` in bash on my Unix system, GIMP is opened up and all of the stuff that GIMP is saying is printed on the calling terminal.

However, when I try to get those messages on Windows by running `gimp` from Cygwin (a batch file that I wrote and put in the C:/Cygwin/bin directory for global access), the program opens, but the nessages do not appear.

Does anyone know why this is and how I can capture GIMP's warning messages on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can activate the [Error Console](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-errors-dialog.html) in GIMP as follows:

- From an image menu: **Windows → Dockable Dialogs → Error Console**
- From the Tab menu in any dockable dialog by clicking on [image: activate button] and selecting **Add Tab → Error Console**

[image: 2]

You can also save all or part of the log to a file.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer - sorry I haven't gotten back to you in a few days. I believe gimp has two error streams, the one it puts on the calling console is much more detailed. Thank you though.'